# where to find the variables that can be changed through drush vset

Tags: drush

There are several variables which we can change through drush vset command like changing the file_temporary_path, maintenance_mode, user_register

I just need to know, how can I know the relevant variable names for which I need to make any changes through drush vset

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variables are saved in the `variables` table in the database. Every module can define its own variables. It is mostly common that the core and contributed modules save their configuration/settings as variables.

It is also mostly common that the modules add a prefix to their variables, so that you can look at the `variables` table in your database and search for the related module if they defined any variables.

Another approach would be looking in the source code of the configuration form for the related field. For example for `file_temporary_path`, you would see:

```
<input type="text" class="form-text" maxlength="255" size="60" value="/tmp"
name="file_temporary_path" id="edit-file-temporary-path">
```

Here is the `name` attribute hints that this configuration field will be saved in `file_temporary_path` variable.

Moreover, if you have [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module installed, there is a **Variable Editor** under the path `devel/variable`, which lists all the variables defined in your site and gives you the possibility to edit or delete them.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a list as such, `vset` simply passes through to [`variable_set()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7), which will accept variables with literally any name.

To get the ones set in your current installation you could run this query:

```
SELECT name FROM variable
```

But bear in mind that variables can also have a default, and so don't necessarily need to be in the variables table to actually exist and be used in the site.

Answer (score 3):

`drush vget` will list the names and values of all variables. If you have Features and [Strongarm](https://drupal.org/project/strongarm) enabled (and you do, of course, you smart developer you), you can also do `drush fc variable`, which will show you the variable names without values.

But as with Clive's answer, these methods only show you variables which have values saved in the database; if a variable exists for which a value hasn't been saved yet and just the default value in code is being used, there's currently not a smart way for Drupal to know that it exists. D8 fixes this, I believe.